# How to declare "is not null" type assertion using Typescript 3.7 Assertion Functions

Tags: typescript, assertion

Currently I'm using following assertion function.

```
// declare
declare function assert(value: unknown): asserts value;

// use
assert(topPort !== null);
assert(bottomPort !== null);
assert(leftPort !== null);
assert(rightPort !== null);
```

I know it's possible to check **is** `null` by following,

```
declare function isNull(value: unknown): asserts value is null
let a = null;
isNull(a)
```

But, how do I check `value` **is not** `null`

```
// this `is not` invalid syntax
declare function isNotNull(value: unknown): asserts value is not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indicated at the bottom of the [Assertion Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) section of the What's New in 3.7, and uses the [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet) utility class.

```
function assertIsDefined<T>(val: T): asserts val is NonNullable<T> {
    if (val === undefined || val === null) {
        throw new Error(
            `Expected 'val' to be defined, but received ${val}`
        );
    }
}
```

Note: the example on the Typescript site uses `AssertionError`, but the example does not work as-is in 3.7.2, so changing it to a plain `Error`.

Comment: Typescript complained about AssertionError parameters. Following worked
new AssertionError({ message: 'Expected 'val' to be not null' });